# Why can't I use `statistics.correlation`?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to compute correlations in Python. My IDE suggests using `statistics.correlation`, but when I try it:

```
import statistics

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
p = statistics.correlation(x, x)
print(p)
```

I get an error that says `AttributeError: module 'statistics' has no attribute 'correlation'`.

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your *Python* version?  -let's confirm it first.  Because *correlation* only becomes available after Python 3.10+

Comment: If you expect something to exist in a library (including the standard library) and errors suggest that it doesn't, the next step is to **read the documentation**.

Comment: Also: please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. We want clear, **direct** questions, and [don't want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/) thanks (it's implicit). I edited the question to show proper style.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.correlation the documentation states it very clearly: this function is only available in 3.10+. Are you sure you are running your code using the correct python version?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/statistics.html#statistics.correlation):

> *New in version 3.10.*

If an older version of Python is used, `statistics.correlation` will not be available.

Try [configuring PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list) to offer suggestions for the correct version of Python (the one actually in use).

Comment: @Thomas - if this help answer your question, please check it so others will also know the info. is useful?